# Argument 2: cannot convert from method group to InfoItem

Tags: c#

**Code:**

```
Dictionary<ValidationType, Func<ValidationModel, InfoItem>> itemValidator = new Dictionary<ValidationType, Func<ValidationModel, InfoItem>>()
{
    { ValidationType.Int32, Validator.ValidateInt }
}  


public static class Validator
{
    public static ValidationModel ValidateInt(InfoItem item)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from method group to InfoItem

I have gone through the other errors in the site but I am still at a loss. The signature to things looks correct to me which I thought was the error to the other answers on the site!

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

`public static ValidationModel ValidateInt(InfoItem item)` is a 
`Func<InfoItem, ValidationModel>`, not `Func<ValidationModel, InfoItem>`.

Out item is always last in `Func`

Answer (score 2):

Since the `ValidateInt` method returns a `ValidationModel` the value type of your dictionary should be `Func<InfoItem, ValidationModel>`. This compiles:

```
Dictionary<ValidationType, Func<InfoItem, ValidationModel>> itemValidator = new Dictionary<ValidationType, Func<InfoItem, ValidationModel>>()
{
    { ValidationType.Int32, Validator.ValidateInt }
};
```

Comment: Thanks again mm8 !!